# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having a problem with blank table data as this method is not getting called after I press search in my `UISearchBar`. I have tried everything and the table is just showing up blanking after pressing search. 
This code takes the description from my `json` url and scans it for the searched word and then puts the index location of whatever description has that search term into an array (`self.indexArray`). 
I would like to the call the table to only display those cells of the index values in that array.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISearchBar *tempSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 40)];
    self.searchBar = tempSearchBar;
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search listings...";

    [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];

}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [self sendData];
}

- (void)sendData
{
    NSString *search = self.searchBar.text;
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MY JSON RETRIEVAL LINK"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:temp];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                     initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation
                                           , id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
        NSLog(@"%@",[responseObject class]);
        self.images = responseObject;
        self.descriptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.images count]; i++)
        {
            [self.descriptions addObject:self.images[i][@"description"]];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < [self.descriptions count]; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d: %@", i, self.descriptions[i]);
            if ([self.descriptions[i] rangeOfString:search options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                NSLog(@"ADDING, %d", i);
                [self.indexArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
            }
        }
        tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,104,320,480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.delegate = self;

        [self.view addSubview:tableView];
        [tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

    [operation start];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"FUNCTION CALLED");
    TLCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TLCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    NSString *name = self.images[indexPath.row][@"name"];
    NSString *location = self.images[indexPath.row][@"location"];
    NSString *body = self.images[indexPath.row][@"description"];
    NSString *list_type = self.images[indexPath.row][@"category"];
    NSString *millisecs = self.images[indexPath.row][@"_createdAt"];

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval ti = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
    double myDouble = [millisecs doubleValue];
    double delta = (ti * 1000) - myDouble;
    NSString *time = [self calculateInterval:delta];

    cell.nameLabel.text = name;
    cell.locationLabel.text = location;
    cell.bodyLabel.text = body;

    CGFloat fixedWidth = cell.bodyLabel.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [cell.bodyLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = cell.bodyLabel.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    cell.bodyLabel.frame = newFrame;

    cell.timeLabel.text = time;

    if ([list_type isEqualToString:@"Sell"])
    {
        UIImageView *thumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sell_icon_small.png"]];
        thumbnailView.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 50., 50.);
        [cell addSubview:thumbnailView];
    }
    else if ([list_type isEqualToString:@"Trade"])
    {
        UIImageView *thumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trade_icon_small.png"]];
        thumbnailView.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 50., 50.);
        [cell addSubview:thumbnailView];
    }
    else if ([list_type isEqualToString:@"Wanted"])
    {
        UIImageView *thumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"want_icon_small.png"]];
        thumbnailView.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 50., 50.);
        [cell addSubview:thumbnailView];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView *thumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ad_icon_small.png"]];
        thumbnailView.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 50., 50.);
        [cell addSubview:thumbnailView];
    }

    NSString *temp = self.images[indexPath.row][@"link"];
    if ([temp isEqualToString:@"no_link"])
    {
        _thereIsAnImage = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        _thereIsAnImage = TRUE;
    }

    if (_thereIsAnImage)
    {

        SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
        [manager downloadWithURL:self.images[indexPath.row][@"link"]
                     options:0
                        progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
         {
             // progression tracking code
         }
                       completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
         {
             if (image)
             {

                 cell.imageView.image = image;

                 cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                 cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
                 cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;


                 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
                 [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
                 [tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
                 [cell.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                 [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

             }
         }];
    }

    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.indexArray.count;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245711/cellforrowatindexpath-is-not-called)

Comment: To be clear, do you have data populate your UITableView before the UISearchBar is activated?

Comment: based on below comments, I would say upload sample project for the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ask that you please check your header file - it should include the following...

```
@interface YourTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
```

Investigate how to implement `UISearchBarDelegate` and `UISearchDisplayDelegate` methods to manage search function in your (table) view controller. Read the Apple documentation [UISearchBarDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [UISearchDisplayDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchDisplayDelegate).

When you use a `UISearchBar`, you need a `UISearchDisplayController` to manage the search results.

If you are not using storyboards, it is important to set the appropriate data source and delegates for instances of both the `UITableView` and the `UISearchDisplayController` in your `UITableViewController`.

Then in your two table view data source methods, you need to provide information to the `searchResultsTableView` (accessed via `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`) so that it knows how to prepare the search results table view.

For example...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger nofRowsInSection = 0;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        nofRowsInSection = self.searchResults.count;
    } else {
        nofRowsInSection = self.indexArray.count;
    }
    return nofRowsInSection;
}
```

...and...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ... <<other code>> ...

    NSString *name = nil;
    NSString *location = nil;
    etc...

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            name = self.searchResults[indexPath.row][@"name"];
            location = self.searchResults[indexPath.row][@"location"];
            ...etc...

    } else {
            name = self.images[indexPath.row][@"name"];
            location = self.images[indexPath.row][@"location"];
            ...etc...

    }

    ... <<other code>> ...
}
```

Note that `self.searchResults` should be an NSMutableArray and it should contain data for the search results table view, prepared by filtering `self.indexArray` based on the search bar text.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it programmatically then you need to set `tableview.delegate = self` and `tableview.datasource = self` in `viewDidLoad` method. Put a breakpoint in `numberOfRowsInSection:` to see the number that it's returning to check whether it's more than zero or not.

Comment: I have the delegates set in viewDidLoad and I put an NSLog in numberOfRowsInSection, which never appears. It seems as though the table methods are never being called.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK . check whether table from storeybaord is connected with the table and delegated correctly.

Comment: I'm actually coding without storyboards. Is there an alternative method to do this recommendation programmatically?

Comment: Then you have custom implementation of `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

to the top of you ViewController.m file?

Comment: Yes, I do. As I said in the other comment, it seems as though none of my table delegate methods are even being called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self` in the viewDidLoad

Comment: I do have them set in viewDidLoad now (instead of in my other function) and the table is still not appearing. None of my table delegate methods are being called at all.